# EXEC function not working in desired manner

Tags: php, mysql, console

I am trying to use `exec()` in php but looks like all my efforts are in vain !!!

Please help me : What is wrong with my code?

```
$cmd = "mysqldump -u root my_db table1 table2 > /home/aditi/Desktop/databasedump.sql";              
$res = exec($cmd , $ot , $res);
```

But I don't see this file. But when I do this on console there is no problem.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few possible causes:

- the password for the dump is missing: `$cmd = "mysqldump -u root -pPassword my_db table1 table2 > /home/aditi/Desktop/databasedump.sql";`
- mysqldump is not in the path when you run a shell: `$cmd = "/usr/bin/mysqldump -u root -pPassword my_db table1 table2 > /home/aditi/Desktop/databasedump.sql";`
- Do not forget that the webserver process runs as another user as when you run the code in a shell. Make sure the webserver user id has access to the folder for writing the dump.

Comment: There is no password set for the db

Comment: try writing the output to /tmp/dump.sql to see if there is a problem with permissions

Comment: Just ran your code on my server (with a password), no problem here!

Comment: When you log in at the console your user name is aditi, and has permissions in /home/aditi. The webserver (apache) runs as www-data (ps aux | grep apache) and has default no permissions to access /home/aditi

Answer (score 1):

The code is correct. Make sure the user which is executing PHP file has permission to write the specified folder.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked other simple commands using exec like echo exec("pwd");. If that is not working means please check whether safe mode has on for your domain. If yes please turn off the safe mode.If that code is running please check the path and permission of the folders.

Answer (score 1):

1. As @Kalai pointed out, try other simple commands to see if `exec` is working at all.
2. `sudo` as the PHP user and execute the same line from the shell to see if it works outside the PHP script. Related: https://serverfault.com/questions/252552/sudoers-syntax-to-run-shell-script-as-php-user